# Angular cli (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/symbol-observable

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

Problem appears after angular cli update to beta 9:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/symbol-observable
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/symbol-observable as "symbol-observable" from http://localhost:4200/vendor/rxjs/Observable.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/symbol-observable(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/symbol-observable(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463
http://localhost:4200/symbol-observable Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

My [package.json](http://wklej.org/id/2702741/) already installed. Updated to latest.
XHR like errors and answers does'nt solve it.
How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe you updated rxjs etc. and forgot to restart the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but I have been unable to get an angular-cli generated app to work with anything above rxjs 5.0.0-beta.6. So do:

```
npm install rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 --save
```

Then

```
ng build
```

That fixed it for me.